# List of questions that we have answered for specific user?

Tags: support, questions, answers

Is there a feature where we can see list of questions that we have answered for a specific user?

Sometimes when I see a question and I see the user who asks the question, I feel familiar with the name, but I can't remember what questions I have already answered for that user. I could just check his question history or my answer history, but it will take some time.

I want to know whether this specific user has asked similar questions before, or whether the user has a good understanding of my previous answers, or maybe just out of my curiosity.

Comment: I've given this question some thought since you asked it, but keep coming to the same conclusion: if it's an active conversation, then you already know about it, and if you can't remember, then it not an active conversation and it doesn't really matter.  If this were a feature request, I'd say it wasn't worth the trouble to implement.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, so you are saying the feature doesn't exist somewhere? some shortcut in the search box that I'm not familiar with, I only know `is:question closed:no answers:0` may be there is another keyword?

Comment: No, I don't think it exists.

Comment: You can query for this sort of thing using [data.se], but the data only refreshes every Monday.

Comment: @Cupcake, Thanks for the pointer, I'll try play with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a [Stack Exchange Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/215843/find-my-answers-for-user-x) that will let you find this information, as long as you have the other user's user ID, and your own user ID:

```sql
SELECT a.Id AS [Post Link], a.CreationDate
FROM Posts q
  INNER JOIN Users u ON q.OwnerUserId = u.Id
  INNER JOIN Posts a ON q.Id = a.ParentID
WHERE u.Id = ##AskerId:int##
  AND a.OwnerUserId = ##UserId##
ORDER BY a.CreationDate DESC
```

Note, however, that the data in SEDE only refreshes once every Monday, so in some cases, you might have to work with stale data.

Comment: The user I'd like to find indeed I never answered his question, but thanks, it works like a charm